# Deserializar un string JSON con C#

Tags: c#, array, json

Pregunta

Estoy recibiendo el siguiente string con formato Json

```
categoria = "[{"CATEGORIA":"COMBUSTIBLE","COSTO":2077.60},
{"CATEGORIA":"MANODEOBRA","COSTO":803.00},
{"CATEGORIA":"MANTENIMIENTO","COSTO":141.00},
{"CATEGORIA":"PEAJESYPARQUEADEROS","COSTO":2.40}]";
```

Para lo cual implemente las siguientes clases

```
public class Categorias
        {
            string categoria { get; set; }
            decimal costo { get; set; }
        }
         
 public class CostoCategoria
        {
            List<Categorias> cat { get; set; }
        }
```

Estoy deserializando con Newtonsoft.Json de la siguiente manera:

```
 var c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CostoCategoria[]>(categorias);
```

La variable c se convierte en un array de 4 elementos, sin embargo cuando lo recorro cada elemento es nulo y no puedo acceder a los valores

Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: public class CostoCategoria
        {
            List<Categorias> categoria { get; set; }
        } debe de llamarse igual no solo "cat"

Answer (score 2):

el problema es el nombre de tus variables, usa `[JsonProperty("CATEGORIA")]` si quieres mantener el nombre de tus variables

tu problema se resuelve de esta manera

```
 var c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CostoCategoria[]>(categoria);
```

te recomiendo esta pagina para convertir tu [json a clases c#](https://app.quicktype.io/)

```
public partial class CostoCategoria
{
  [JsonProperty("CATEGORIA")]
  public string Categoria { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("COSTO")]
  public double Costo { get; set; }
}
```

puedes ver tu resultado aqui https://dotnetfiddle.net/sEpswG

Answer (score 0):

Puedes trabajarlo asi:

```
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var CostoCategoria = new ser.Deserialize<List<CostoCategorias>>(jsonData);

public class Categoria
{
    string categoria { get; set; }
    decimal costo { get; set; }
}
public class CostoCategorias
{
    public Categoria categorias;
}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).